# How to enable the global search in salesforce

Tags: global-search, search-layout

EDIT:

[image]

How to turn on the Global Search to search of any custom or standard fields?

I have done the following so far:

```
 Setup --> Customize --> Search --> Search Settings. 
          (selected my custom object for both "Enhanced Lookups" "Lookup Auto-Completion"
```

Also I have tried to Search on employee__c Owner field.

Modify Search Layouts of `employee__c` object:

```
employee__c -> Search Layouts ->  Edit layout
```

And selected fields column

But still could not able to search on the field I have added which is "Start_Date__c"

Comment: You might consider using reports or list views to find these records instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure you have a tab created for your object.
Please see this link:
[Searchable Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields_custom_object.htm&language=en)

Also, You need to make the custom field as "External Id". Follow this blog by Jeff Douglous for detailed information:
[Working with External Id fields](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/05/07/using-exernal-id-fields-in-salesforce/)

Comment: i do have custom tab associated with the object.

Comment: @NickKahn You need to make the custom field as "External Id". Follow this blog by Jeff Douglous for detailed information: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/05/07/using-exernal-id-fields-in-salesforce/

Comment: Please let me know if this helps

Comment: Based on the blog you provided I can't event have search on datetime field.

Comment: I am afraid Nick, thats a limitation salesforce enforces on these fields.

Comment: his blog post is really old 07 May 2010

Comment: It is still the same for date time fields. You can try creating a new date time field or edit a date time Field, and you won't see an option to make it as External Id.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not mean to be rude but I was just noticing his blog dated and things have changed since 2010 in SF world,  I'm not sure about make it as external id maybe that was right back in 2010 but it will allow you to add up to 10 fields for search in the search layout... what does the external Id has to do here? in one of my project I have 10 fields in the search layout...

Comment: No worries Nick, I am just trying to help here. You want to add the field in Search layouts or in Global Search ?

Comment: in the global search i have updated my question with screen shot, pls have a look

Comment: To enable global search for any field, you must make it as external Id. Thats the only way i suppose. You can try and verify this by doing this for any other field, other than dateTime

Answer (score 0):

I know it's little late but in my case i followed the below mentioned steps:- 
1) Setup
2) Chatter Setting
3) Turn on Chatter and Global Search features = Check the checkbox below this and save