# Make Custom '__c' Field Searchable in Global Search Bar

Tags: custom-field, opportunity-lineitem, search, externalid, global-search

I have a custom field at the Opportunity Product level that can't be searched at the moment on the global search, even if I click on 'search all'

I have seen [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtnxAAA) link that selects 'external ID' on that field but it still can't be searched! If it isn't possible at this level, can anyone suggest other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: What type of field is it?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Its a 'Text' field forgot to mention...

Comment: Probably similar Question: [how-to-enable-the-global-search-in-salesforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131925/how-to-enable-the-global-search-in-salesforce)

Comment: Tried that as well @RohitMourya but that doesn't work either!

Comment: Well, if you must do this, and you are not opposed to unattractive solutions, then you could just put a copy of your opportunity product information in a custom object and search through that. You can keep them synced with either workflow rules, or perhaps process builder, or triggers. Not pretty, but i'd guess it's possible.

Comment: @Kasper I guess I can try with that to see if it works for me - Does that mean there will be 2 exact copies of all fields in every opp product? (one called opp product as it is now and one called 'my new custom object'?) Are there any tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any tutorials. Thinking of it i don't think you could do this with workflows, but processbuilder in combination with flows should work, or if you are familiar with apex then i'd go for triggers. Basically what you'd do is create a custom object with a lookup to your opportunity product. Then when a opportunity product is created you also create a custom object record, and link the two . When the opportunity product is changed, the custom record needs to be looked up and also needs to change. On the custom object you only need the fields that you need for your search.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not due to your custom field, but the object it resides on.

Opportunity products do not seem to be returned using the global search. You should upvote this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kw6sAAA).

Comment: Does it work on the opportunity level? Maybe I can reference the field content of my custom field in opps product level to opportunity level...?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the object you're referencing but I have a solution for this issue that I have used many times previously.

If I want to search for records by account name for a custom object in which I can't search by account name to find related records... This is what I do in order to be able to search for those records:

- Create a custom text field, e.g., Account Name Searchable
- Check the External Id box
- Create a WFR with criteria as "TRUE"
- Set it to fire every time a record is created or edited
- Create a FU to input the related account records name into the Account Name Searchable custom field

The above is a specific example for a lookup to an account. Obviously switch out whatever is necessary for your use case. Additionally, I created this solution prior to Process Builder so you could use that as well.